# Delete order negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table sales order header

[image]

a second table sales order line

[image]

I need to exclude all sales order number that contains at least one negative quatity value

Expected results: sales order header 
I will get

[image]

sales order line

[image]

I try

```
select salesordernumber ,salesorderline ,QTY ,date ,codeArticle

from salesorderline
where qty>0
```

I get wrong results

[image]

How could I do the same for sales order header?

Comment: Your `Final Result`: Is that what you want, or what you have? What is your expected end result?

Comment: @JerryM. I mean what I expected, just as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select salesordernumber ,salesorderline ,QTY ,date ,codeArticle
from salesorderline a
where not exists 
    (select 1 from salesorderline b where a.salesordernumber=b.salesordernumber and qty<0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script with sub query to filter out order with negative quantity-

```
SELECT * FROM salesorderline
WHERE salesordernumber IN (
    SELECT salesordernumber
    FROM salesorderline
    GROUP BY salesordernumber
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN QTY <0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
```